# How to perform data binning in DolphinDB?

Tags: cut, dolphindb, quantile

I want to bin data by equal width and equal frequency, which can be achieved by using functions `qcut` or `cut` in Python. How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Equal width binning divides data into intervals with equal width but the data volume of each bin varies. In DolphinDB, you can use the `bucket` function.

Equal frequency binning divides data evenly into intervals with equal data volume. In DolphinDB, you can use the `rank` function to specify the groupNum or use the `bar` function to specify the interval.